# ListKeys permissions required for adding queue message to Azure Storage using Windows Powershell Az module

Tags: powershell, azure-storage-queues, powershell-az-module

Using the Az module for Powershell I need to put a message onto an Azure Storage queue. Proper RBAC permissions are assigned. I can do this just fine with the Azure CLI (which at the moment I cannot use on my target system unfortunately).

```
    function azLoginWithServicePrincipal {
        $tid = "tenant-id-guid"
        $appId = "app-id-guid"
        $thumb = "cert-thumbprint"
        Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tid -CertificateThumbprint $thumb -ApplicationId $appId
    }
    
    function enqueueMessage {
        param([string]$rg, [string]$acc, [string]$queue, [object]$msg)
        
        $json = [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage]::new(($msg | ConvertTo-Json)) 
        $storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $acc -ResourceGroupName $rg
        $q = Get-AzStorageQueue –Name $queue –Context $storageAccount.Context
        $q.CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync($json)
    }


azLoginWithServicePrincipal
$data = @{ data= "some-text-data"}
enqueueMessage -rg "my-rg" -acc "my-storage-account" -queue "my-queue-name" -msg $data
```

Here's the output. You can see that there seems to be a permissions mismatch. ListKeys on that storage account is required. But why, this seems excessive. Moreover, AccountKeys have been disabled for that storage account, there is RBAC-only. Moreover, using the Azure CLI (and simpler syntax) that same security principal can add to the queue no problemo.

```
Get-AzStorageQueue: The client 'client-id-guid' with object id 'object-id-guid' does not have authorization to perform action
'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' over scope
'/subscriptions/subscription-id-guid/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account' or the scope is
invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

Answer (score 3):

•   I tried to execute the same commands as stated by you in the question in my subscription where I have **‘Contributor’ Azure role assignment** in my subscription and only a **‘User’ Azure AD role**. I **created a storage account and a storage queue accordingly in my resource group and created an application registration to be used as a service principal for logging in to the storage queue and adding a message to the queue**.

Please find the below snapshots for your reference: -

[image: Add message queue function]

[image: Azure portal snapshot]

According to the above, I was successfully able to add messages to the queue storage as I have the below permissions that are necessarily required for this purpose: -

```
    Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listkeys/action
```

Also, you should have one of the below Azure roles assigned to your ID for this purpose: -

```
  The Reader and Data Access role
  The Storage Account Contributor role
  The Azure Resource Manager Contributor role
  The Azure Resource Manager Owner role
```

Therefore, **when a storage account is locked with an Azure Resource Manager ‘ReadOnly’ lock, the ‘List Keys’ operation is not permitted for that storage account. List Keys is a ‘POST’ operation, and all ‘POST’ operations are prevented when a ‘ReadOnly’ lock is configured for the account. For this reason, when the account is locked with a ReadOnly lock, users must use Azure AD credentials to access blob data in the portal**.

For more information regarding this, please refer to the links below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal#use-the-account-access-key***

Comment: This worked for me and it seems that "Reader and Data Access" is the minimal role to assign.  What I find frustrating is that this seems to only be needed for the Az commands.  No other use (Data Factory, REST API, etc) which adds, gets, moves files around seem to require this.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, and after calling the command to set the subscription it worked.

```
  az account set --subscription $subscription_id
```